# Delphi 10.2.3 hangs when starting (with debugging) a 32 bit application

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Update:  as noted by some, this is a problem brought about by NOD32.  An issue item for this in their system is:

https://forum.eset.com/topic/16237-probleme-debug-delphi-with-eset-11249/

---

Delphi 10.2.1 and 10.2.3 hang when starting (with debugging) any 32 bit application on Windows 10/64.  This started after the computer was rebooted for the weekend like it is every weekend.

Debugging a 64 bit project compiles & runs ok.
Debugging a 32 bit project compiles but hangs before/slightly after the project even starts running ("end task" on Delphi is the only option now).  If I run without the debugger, the project runs ok.  Delphi "stops responding".

I've seen this single form "do nothing" test application I have used to investigate this freeze after loading Kernel32 or Comdlg32.

Hearing how similar this is to the problems with Delphi 10.2 and Windows 10's Creator update, I migrated to Delphi 10.2.3.  Same problem as before.

I restored to a backup of the Windows partition.  After I did that, it worked until I rebooted and then it broke again.

I went to an earlier backup of the Windows partition & got the same result.

This is so strange...any ideas?

Comment: I have recently seen a similar complaint from someone using the latest Windows 10 Insider Preview.

Comment: I had the same problem. I found the cause - it is antivirus program NOD32, the latest version 10.2. I had to downgrade to 10.1. 
ESET is informed and they try to solve the issue.

Comment: … in the above post version refer to NOD32, not to Delphi

Comment: I'm on NOD 11.2 and the only thing that addresses the problem is to disable RealTimeProtection.  For the moment, I shall work that way and see what ESET has to say about this.  Thank you for your comments; at least I'm back to work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I Thought it might relate to Nod32 as I had the same issue happen after a nod 32 update.

I have added the BDS.exe directory to be excluded from real time file system protection.

Seems to be fine now.

Comment: I also had to add the directory for my projects so it was probably that directory.

Comment: No Luck still hanging on debug. did work if I shut down nod32.

Comment: as I said above - downgrade nod32 to ver 10.1

Comment: I'm on NOD 11.2 and the only thing that addresses the problem is to disable RealTimeProtection.  For the moment, I shall work that way and see what ESET has to say about this.  Thank you for your comments; at least I'm back to work!

Answer (score 5):

I have seen this kind of behavior with F-Secure antivirus and Windows 10 1803 (April 2018 Update).
This is similar to the last comments on this post : http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2017-june-delphi-packages-creators-update.html.

The only workaround I've found was to define the affinity of the BDS.exe process.

You can do this by right clicking the bds.exe process in the Details tab of the Task Manager and Define affinity but it will only define it for the current run.

You can define affinity definitively by running BDS through the command line.

Here is my shortcut :

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C START /affinity 1 bds.exe
```

Comment: I had this a couple of weeks ago with ESET Antivirus and Firewall. I disabled both and I was enabling features one at a time after the debugging was working. TBH, I am not sure if that was the real problem cause now ESET is fully on and debugging works.

Comment: Disabling the F-Secure FSGKHS service also solved the problem for me, so I think it's related to the antivirus scanning BDS or the debugged program.

Comment: Please contact F-Secure for this or/and fill a report case on https://quality.embarcadero.com/ so Embarcadero can contact the antivirus editor and help them to fix the false positive error.

Comment: Thank you, your affinity work-around worked for me, +1

Answer (score 1):

ESET is deploying 11.2.63.0 release of it's antivirus and the problem of freezing Delphi for Win32 debugging is now solved.